# CSS: making search box active on the first tab click

Tags: css, tabindex

The question consists of two parts:

1. Is it ok (from the UX/UI p.o.v.) to make a search box on the page activated on the first tab keypress?
2. How to do it technically keeping the rest of the tabbing mechanism intact (e.g. the first element activated on tab keypress by default is now activated right after the search box on the second tab keypress)?

Answer (score 1):

1. For the desktop browsers it okay. But bad UX for the mobile browser as it will popup the keyboard focus automatically comes to search box.
2. Set attribute **tabindex="0"** for the elements programmatically using JavaScript after the the search box leaves focus. Use onblur() event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabindex=1` attribute in your search input element to achieve. Like this,

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" tabindex="1" />
```

Whether you should or not, [This article might help](https://web.dev/control-focus-with-tabindex/)